# Align multiple tables horizontally?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want multiple tables horizontally. It works in Firefox, but not Chrome. Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {background-color:#000000;}
table {border:1px solid #FFFFFF; float:left;}
tr, td {background-color:#000000; border:1px solid #00000;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table id="t1">

<tr>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

</table>
<table id="t2">

<tr>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked in Chrome, it's working fine

```html
<style>
body {background-color:#000000;}
table {border:1px solid #FFFFFF; float:left;}
tr, td {background-color:#000000; border:1px solid #00000;}
</style>

<table id="t1">

<tr>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

</table>
<table id="t2">

<tr>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Svbz2/

Answer (score 1):

In order for the float property to work, you'll usually need to specify the width of the object you're trying to float. Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {background-color:#000000;}
table {border:1px solid #FFFFFF; width:200px; float:left;}
tr, td {background-color:#000000; border:1px solid #00000;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table id="t1">

<tr>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

</table>
<table id="t2">

<tr>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's also important to note that using tables as a structure for a layout is not the 'semantically correct' way of doing it. Seems like you're using it as a structure for a web form - maybe consider using floating divs instead?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how chrome wouldn't like this. Is it necessary to use multiple tables? Maybe you should of filled that required extra text with the purpose of this page.. A better approach could be to use DIV (to define sections on the page) or UL (unordered list with no list-style) but again, no idea what this page is doing.